# How to run function in Preference class from PreferenceActivity

Tags: java, android, preferenceactivity, dialog-preference

There are only so many types of Preference types we can set in PreferenceActivity. I am trying to run a specific function once a certain preference is clicked. Is there a way to override a preferenceScreen or editText onClick?

Comment: That's what the PrefrenceActivity is for. And btw I think you mean method not function right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can. Here's a simple example of how to get the preference reference and execute custom code on a click event.

```
public class ActivityPreferences extends PreferenceActivity
{
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        addPreferencesFromResource( R.xml.preferences );

        Preference myPref = findPreference( "MY_PREF" );
        myPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener( new OnPreferenceClickListener()
        {
            public boolean onPreferenceClick( Preference pref )
            {
                  // Run your custom method
            }
        } );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahmad, yes - method sorry. Robert, what type of preference does "MY_PREF" have to be so that there are no other ex. Check boxes being checked or text field popping up afterward? 

Thanks

Comment: MY_PREF is the preference key. myPref is of the top level Preference type. If you want, you can cast it to whatever subclass of Preference you are using: CheckboxPreference myPref = (CheckboxPreference)findPreference( "MY_PREF" );

Comment: But is there a specific subclass that does not have a check box that will turn on and off etc. One that will function primarily as an onClick. One that does not do anything else once clicked.

Comment: Yes, the top level Preference.

Comment: @MorganCulbertson please flag the answer as correct